# cant understand how to use ci_reporter gem

Tags: ruby, rake, testunit

I cant understand how the usage of the [ci_reporter](http://rubydoc.info/gems/ci_reporter/1.7.3/frames) gem works.  How do I modify my rakefile "to make the ci:setup:testunit task a dependency of your test tasks"  I don't understand how to do what this is asking me to do.  Can anyone explain?
Thanks

```
#this isn't legal ruby! ARG!!!!! 
task :myNewTask => ci:setup:testunit
```

Comment: Your problem seems to boil down to "I don't know how to specify dependencies in a `Rakefile`". [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I understood dependencies to mean task :myNewTask => :myDependency @willglynn

Comment: The part I don't understand is the ci:setup:testunit task or how to reference this in order to make it a dependency of an existing rake task

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to specify is as a string not a symbol.

```
   task :myNewTask => "ci:setup:testunit"
```